# CakePHP Form action from other controller

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Well, I have a CakePHP 2.2.5 app which is basically management of users, and a user has a photo, and I create a PhotosController (as suggestion of this [tutorial](http://goo.gl/oglQn)). I tested it and it works perfectly on `Photos/View`, including the ajax elements to be possible send a photo in a form without redirecting. And now I'm trying to connect all of this, but it ins't as easy as I think it should be.

My Photo add method:

```
public function add()
{
    if ( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {           
        $this->Photo->create();
        $json = array( 'result' => array( 'files' => array() ) );
        if ( $this->Photo->save( $this->request->data ) ) {
            $photo                             = $this->Photo->findById( $this->Photo->id );
            $json['files'][0]['name']          = $photo['Photo']['basename'];
            $json['files'][0]['size']          = $this->request->data['Photo']['file']['size'];
            $json['files'][0]['url']           = $this->webroot . 'media/transfer/img/' . $photo['Photo']['basename'];
            $json['files'][0]['thumbnail_url'] = $this->webroot . 'media/filter/thumbnail/img/' . $photo['Photo']['basename'];
        }
        else {
            $json = 'Error';
            $this->Session->setFlash( __( 'The photo could not be saved. Please, try again.' ) );
        }
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs( $this , 'ajax' );
        Configure::write( 'debug' , 0 );
        $this->set( 'json' , json_encode( $json ) );
        $this->render( '/Elements/ajax' );
    }
```

My test View (on users controller):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(
        'Photo' ,
        array( 'url'     => array( 'controller' => 'photos' ,
                                   'action'     => 'add'
        ) ,
               'id'      => 'fileupload' ,
               'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        )
    ); ?>
<-- Some HTML HERE-->
<?php
                echo $this->TB->input(
                    'Photo.file' ,
                    array(
                        'prepend' => 'Upload' ,
                        'type'    => 'file' ,
                        'class'   => 'fileUpload' ,
                        //'multiple' => 'multiple',
                        'div'     => FALSE ,
                        'between' => FALSE ,
                        'after'   => FALSE ,
                        'label'   => FALSE ,
                        'help'    => NULL ,
                    )
                );
                ?>
</form>
<-- Some (already tested) Javascript to make this work HERE-->
```

The view renders without php errors, but when I upload a file I get an Javascript error, and the debug says:

```
GET http://<server>/<app>/users/add 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:1960
  send jquery.min.js:1960
  b.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:1840
  (anonymous function) main.js:59
  c jquery.min.js:215
  p.fireWith jquery.min.js:249
  b.extend.ready jquery.min.js:69
  H jquery.min.js:10
```

Actually, I get this error on both, GET and POST methods (with some different line of jQuery of course).

Even the action is set to the PhotosController it is trying to access the Users. I think because of the view, as I din't specify users anywhere. I am trying to solve this problem for a week and I don't have more ideas.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it cakephp 2.2.5 by any chance? You might be stepping a bit into the future

Comment: The html-result of the `$this->Form->create()`, does it have the correct action? Can you check with firebug or similar?

Comment: Yes, it render the correct action: <form action="/<app>/photos/add" id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="">